# JavaScript- Implementing a Grid rotating algorithm

Tags: javascript, algorithm, gridview, grid

**The goal is to achieve the following** :

**Context**: Laying out nine (9) buttons to form a 3 x 3 grid inside a div​ and modifying their labels after each click event on one of the buttons.

**Important**: The labels on the outer button must rotate in a clockwise direction each time we click the middle button

Initial State:

```
1  2  3
4  5  6
7  8  9
```

After Clicking the middle button (button 5) 1 time:

```
4  1  2
7  5  3
8  9  6
```

After Clicking the middle button (button 5) 2 times:

```
7  4  1
8  5  2
9  6  3
```

**Task**: Write an algorithm to rotate the outer buttons in a clockwise direction every time the middle button (button 5) is clicked.

The shuffle_grid function has been bound to the number "5". 
Below is the HTML:

```
<div id="keypad">
<input type='button' value='1' id='keys'>
      <input type='button' value='2' id='keys'>
      <input type='button' value='3' id='keys'>
      <br>
      <input type='button' value='4' id='keys'>
      <input type='button' value='5' id='keys' onclick= shuffle_grid()>
      <input type='button' value='6' id='keys'>
      <br>
      <input type='button' value='7' id='keys'>
      <input type='button' value='8' id='keys'>
      <input type='button' value='9' id='keys'>
      </div>
```

Below is the challenging part, the JavaScript:

```
function shuffle_grid() { 
}
```

what should I put into this function to fulfill this task?

Comment: "Urgent" pleas don't help you at all.

Answer (score 1):

Think of the order around the square (1,2,3,6,9,8,7,4) and you should be on your way. Theres probably even more elegant ways but thats the first I thought of.

Comment: I've been stuck on it for a long time. I'm on code pen. If you have any ideas give me a link. I'm almost out of time.

Comment: It will need some kind of formula because I'll have to manipulate each input value. I thought of using a list of preset values but that doesn't seem like a good solution. Too cumbersome and prone to bugs.